# Add values to array on change radio input group

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have many groups of radio inputs for example:

1. there are 3 radios with name="group1",
2. 4 radios with name="group2"
3. 2 radios with name="group3"

All of those fields have value with price to add to totals.

Now, in jQuery when onchange each of those inputs, I want to add it's value to total price, but when its in the same group, this price should be added to original price, if not the same group, it should be added to new price, with previously added value.
The groups of inputs are importing from database, so there can be even 10 groups, I want to make this dynamic, so client can check one of input from group and the value will be added to the price correctly.

Could someone help me?

Here is example screen:
[image]

```
var inputprice_arr = new Array();
var inputprice = new Array();

$(document).on('change', ".tab-pane.active .cechy-wrapper .cecha input[type=radio]", function() {
    group = $(this).attr('name');
    inputprice = parseFloat($(this).val().split(' ')[0]);
});
```

Comment: Add all relevant code to OP to show what you have tried so far. Not an image only

Comment: So all this operation will be done on client side or server side? And if it will be done on server side are you using ajax for data submission?

Comment: All operations of calculating values are made in jQuery, client side. I was trying to make only in jquery/js with no ajax.